# SQL Server 2008 R2 Full Text Secondary Data File

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database with a full text catalog.  It appears that the FT catalog is currently in the primary data file (MDF).  I want to move or re-create the FT catalog in a secondary data file (NDF) so I can place it on a different set of disks.  Does anyone have any experience with this process?

I've played around with it for hours and researched quite a bit by now.  I can create the .ndf and it only appears to grow in size when I add individual tables to it through the wizard.  I need some way to move an entire existing FT catalog or index to the ndf.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the index you can state the filegroup that you want the index to be created in, just like any other index. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx

Create a new filegroup containing one or more data files then recreate your full text indexes including the "on «filegroup»" option.  Doesn't look like you can use with drop existing on full text indexes, so you'll need to drop it first.

Or you could give this a go.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240867#top

Apologies if its not quite what youre after, I'm on my phone and its late!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It looks like the ON FILEGROUP option was eliminated in 08 though for when you create the catalog, not the indexes that go into it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189520.aspx  Do I just create the catalog without that option and then specify the ON FILEGROUP when I add the indexes?  Maybe that's what I've been missing this whole time, I will test today.

Comment: Yes I believe so, sorry I don't have access to an instance at the moment so I'm unable to test for you.

Comment: Thank you! Your guidance put me in the right direction, I was trying to specify the filegroup option in the create full text catalog statement which 08 ignores, I needed to specify the filegroup in the create full text index statements.  like the example here                                                      USE AdventureWorks2008;GOCREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftCatalog;GOCREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON HumanResources.JobCandidate(Resume) KEY INDEX PK_JobCandidate_JobCandidateIDon ([ftCatalog], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY]);GO   Once I have a 15 reputation or higher I'll be able to promote your response :)

Comment: Cheers :) If you're happy to could you click the tick mark to mark my post as your 'accepted answer'?